# Is a core for the generator of a Feller semi-group invariant under the resolvent?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, semigroup-of-operators

Let $\{T_t:t\geq 0\}$ be a Feller semi-group acting on $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ with generator $(A,\mathcal{D}_A)$. We know a subspace $D\subset \mathcal{D}_A$ is a *core* for $A$ if $(\lambda-A)D$ is dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ for some $\lambda>0$. Another condition for a subspace $D\subset \mathcal{D}_A$ to be a core for $A$ is that it be dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ and invariant under the semi-group, i.e. $T_t(D)\subset D$ for all $t\geq 0$. For $\alpha>0$, let $R_{\alpha}:C_0(\mathbb{R})\to \mathcal{D}_A$ be the corresponding resolvent operator, i.e. $R_{\alpha}=(\alpha-A)^{-1}=\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-\alpha t)T_t dt$. Notice that $\mathcal{D}_A$ is a core for $A$ and that $R_{\alpha}\mathcal{D}_A\subset \mathcal{D}_A$. My question is whether this invariance under the resolvent holds for every core or perhaps there is some easy to check condition that implies resolvent invariance in certain cases.

Answer (score 3):

In general, cores fail to be invariant under the resolvent (see the example below). However, invariance under the resolvent is a **sufficient** condition for a set to be a core. More precisely:

> Let $(T_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Feller semigroup with generator $(A,\mathcal{D}_A)$ and resolvent $(R_{\alpha})_{\alpha>0}$. If $\mathcal{D} \subseteq C_0(\mathbb{R})$ is a dense subset such that $R_{\alpha}(\mathcal{D}) \subseteq \mathcal{D}$ for some $\alpha>0$, then $\mathcal{D}$ is a core for the generator $(A,\mathcal{D}_A)$.

For a proof see e.g. *Lévy Matters III* by Böttcher, Schilling & Wang, Lemma 1.34.

The following example shows that invariance under the resolvent is not necessary for being a core:

**Example:** Let $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Poisson process with intensity $1$. The associated semigroup is given by

$$T_t f(x) := \mathbb{E}f(x+N_t), \qquad f \in C_0(\mathbb{R}), t \geq 0, x \in \mathbb{R},$$

and it is not difficult to see that $(T_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Feller semigroup acting on $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ with generator

$$Af(x) = f(x+1)-f(x), \qquad f \in \mathcal{D}_A := C_0(\mathbb{R}).$$

Clearly, the space of smooth functions with compact support $C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is a core for the generator $(A,C_0(\mathbb{R}))$. Now let $f \in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ be a non-negative function such that $f(0)>0$. Since $\mathbb{P}(N_t=k)>0$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $t>0$ we have

$$(R_{\alpha} f)(-k) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\alpha t} \mathbb{E}f(-k+N_t) \, dt \geq f(0) \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\alpha t} \mathbb{P}(-k+N_t=0) \, dt >0$$

for any $\alpha>0$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. This shows that $R_{\alpha} f$ does not have compact support; in particular, $R_{\alpha} f \notin C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. This proves that the core $\mathcal{D} := C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ does **not** satisfy the relation $R_{\alpha} \mathcal{D} \subseteq \mathcal{D}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is a counter example.
Take the Feller semigroup $T=\{T_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ of a negative drift stopped at $0$,  defined as 
\begin{equation}
T_tf(x):=\left\{\begin{split}
f(x-t), & \quad &x>t,\\
f(0), &\quad  &x\le t,
\end{split}
\right.
\end{equation}
on the space $C_0([0,\infty))$ of real-valued continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$ vanishing at infinity equipped with the supremum norm. Then the generator is
$$
Af(x):=\left\{\begin{split}
-\partial_xf(x), & \quad &x>0,\\
0, &\quad  &x=0,
\end{split}
\right.
$$
with the domain 
$$
\mathcal D_A =\{f\in C^1((0,\infty)),\ \partial_xf(x)\in C_0((0,\infty)),\ \partial_xf(0+)=0\}
$$
Take $$
D:= \{f\in \mathcal D_A: \ \partial_{xxx}f(0+)=0, \text{ derivatives up to the third exist and are in } C_0([0,\infty))\}.
$$ Observe that the subspace $D$ is dense in $\mathcal D_A$ and invariant under the semigroup $T$, hence it is a core for $(A,\mathcal D_A)$.
Pick any $f\in D$ such that $\partial_{xx}f(0+)\neq 0$, fix $\alpha>0$ and compute $\partial_{xxx}R_\alpha f(0+)$. For $x>0$
\begin{align}
\partial_{xxx}R_\alpha f(x) &= \partial_{xxx}\left(\int_0^x e^{-\alpha t}f(x-t)dt+f(0+)\alpha^{-1}e^{-\alpha x}\right)\\
 &= \partial_{xx}\left(\int_0^x e^{-\alpha t}\partial_xf(x-t)dt\right)\\
 &= \partial_{x}\left(\int_0^x e^{-\alpha t}\partial_{xx}f(x-t)dt+ e^{-\alpha x}\partial_xf(0+)\right)\\
 &= \partial_{x}\left(\int_0^x e^{-\alpha t}\partial_{xx}f(x-t)dt\right)\\
 &=\int_0^x e^{-\alpha t}\partial_{xxx}f(x-t)dt+e^{-\alpha x}\partial_{xx}f(0+).
\end{align}
Then $\lim_{x\downarrow 0}\partial_{xxx}R_\alpha f(x) = \partial_{xx}f(0+)\neq 0$, which implies that $R_\alpha f \notin D$. $\quad\square$

Observe that the core
$$
\tilde D:= \{f\in \mathcal D_A: \ \partial_{xx}f(0+)=0, \text{ derivatives up to the second exist and are in } C_0([0,\infty))\}
$$
would be invariant under $R_\alpha$, which makes me suspect that the invariance of the core under the resolvent is generally hard to check at least on bounded domains.